# Not sure how to fix this error Luhn Algorithm PYTHON

Tags: python, luhn

Alright,
So I think i'm almost there,
my first/second part work perfect when they are on their own, but i'm having trouble combining the two
this is what I have so far
I'm thinking the error is in the last bit, 
sorry, im new with python, so i'm hoping to get the hang of it soon

Edit3: i've gotten it to work (with the help of you guys) but now when i input 3782822463100050, its suppose to be invalid american express, but its showing up as valid american express...

Edit1: Okay, for example when i post `0378282246310005` (a fake american express) it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nat/Desktop/attempt.py", line 39, in <module>
    print((cardType)+"Valid")
NameError: name 'cardType' is not defined
```

but when i insert a random number like `0378282246310005` it works

Please enter your credit card number 0378282246310005

We do not accept that kind of card

Edit2: in the end you should be able to type in a credit card number and it'll say "Your "type of credit card" is valid (or invalid)

or say that "we dont support the card"

```
#GET number that will be tested
CreditNumber = input("Please enter your credit card number")

#SET total to 0
total=0

#LOOP backwards from the last digit to the first, one at a time
CreditCount = len(CreditNumber)
for i in range(0, CreditCount, -1):
    LastDigit=CreditCard[i]

#IF the position of the current digit is even THEN DOUBLE the value of the current digit
    if i % 2 ==0:
        LastDigit=LastDigit*2

#IF the doubled value is more than 9 THEN SUM the digits of the doubled value
        if LastDigit>9:
            LastDigit=LastDigit/10+LastDigit%10

    total=total + digit

#Figure out what credit card the user has
if ( CreditNumber[0:2]=="34" or CreditNumber[ 0:2 ] == "37"):
     cardType = "Your American Express is"

elif ( CreditNumber[ 0 :4 ] =="6011"):
       cardType = "Your Discover card is"

elif ( CreditNumber[0 :2 ]  in [ "51", "52", "53", "54", "55"]):
       cardType = "Your Mastercard is"

elif ( CreditNumber == "4" ):
       cardType = "Your VISA card is"

else:
       print( "We do not accept that kind of card")

if total % 10 == 0:
    print((cardType)+"Valid")

else:
    print((cardType)+"Invalid")
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is not working right now? Show the full stack trace. If you don't have any errors, what output are you getting that does not meet your expectation? You want to put together a [mcve] to help the reader know how to help you.

Comment: I added the edits ! thanks

Comment: This is a minor nitpick, and not really relevant to your question, but you should consider reserving CapitalCaseNames for class names and not variable names. It's a standard in almost every language.

Answer (score 1):

in the control statements under the comment  `#Figure out what credit card the user has`, the variable `cardType` is defined in every branch except `else`. Since the name was never defined outside the scope of the control statement, the interpreter gives you a NameError when you try to access the variable when the code followed the else branch of the if statement.

to fix this you can do a couple of different things. you can create a a special value for `cardType` when `CardNumber` is invalid and check for it in the next control statement:

```
if ...:
    ...
else:
    cardType = "some special value"

if cardType == "some special value":
    ...
```

or you could use a try/except statement:

```
try:
    print(cardType)
except NameError:
    print("invalid card number")
```

**EDIT**: Also you should note that currently the `total` variable will always be `0` as the for loop doesn't actually run. If you want to decrement a range, the first argument should be greater than the second, or the range function will just create an empty list.

Comment: okay that makes sense, but now i am confused. How would I let python know that "else" means anything that is not listed above? I thought that was the point of "else"? I know i'm thinking about the wrong way :/

Comment: @NatalieRenee Just create a default for `cardType` before your conditional statements. Maybe an example can be provided in the answer to provide some clarity

Comment: or maybe my answer wasn't clear. I'll change it to show some examples of how to fix it

Comment: You just need to define `cardType`  in the else statement, such as `cardType = 'Your card is'`

Comment: The better approach is to actually declare the variable before entering the conditional statements.

Comment: I added cardType="", which seemed to have fixed the error but now, when i input some values, there output isnt the correct answer

Comment: I made an edit to my answer which will probably fix your bug.